# How to know which X509 Certificate Signed another Certificate (Java)

Tags: java, certificate, x509, decoding, subject

There are three certificates in my example, assume they form a chain but i don't know yet which of them signed which:

```
X509Certificate c1 = ....
X509Certificate c2 = ....
X509Certificate c2 = ....
```

I would like to know which certificate is responsible for signing the other certificate.

The plan was to get the "[AuthorityKeyIdentifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-27)" and match it with the "[SubjectKeyIdentifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-28)".

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1. DEROctetString;

private static String decodeKey(byte[] e) {
    DEROctetString octet = new DEROctetString(e);
    return octet.toString();
}

String subjectKeyId = decodeKey(c.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.14"));
String authorityKeyId = decodeKey(c.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.35"));
```

Im getting the following for the certificates (in order of the chain): subject/authority key ID pair

Values of the SubjectKeyIdentifier and AuthorityKeyIdentifier  after Decoding:

Certificate 1: (end of the chain)

```
#0416041482b7384a93aa9b10ef80bbd954e2f10ffb809cde
#04183016801482b7384a93aa9b10ef80bbd954e2f10ffb809cde
```

Certificate 2: Signed by Certificate 1

```
#04160414ab8059c365836d1d7d13bd19c3ec1a8f0d476aa3
#04183016801482b7384a93aa9b10ef80bbd954e2f10ffb809cde
```

Certificate 3: Signed by Certificate 2

```
(no SubjectKeyIdentifier - null bytes)
#041830168014ab8059c365836d1d7d13bd19c3ec1a8f0d476aa3
```

Formatted and Aligned for Easy Reading (Same thing as the one on top)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Certificate 1
#04 16 04 14       82 b7 38 4a 93 aa 9b 10 ef 80 bb d9 54 e2 f1 0f fb 80 9c de
#04 18 30 16 80 14 82 b7 38 4a 93 aa 9b 10 ef 80 bb d9 54 e2 f1 0f fb 80 9c de

Certificate 2
#04 16 04 14       ab 80 59 c3 65 83 6d 1d 7d 13 bd 19 c3 ec 1a 8f 0d 47 6a a3
#04 18 30 16 80 14 82 b7 38 4a 93 aa 9b 10 ef 80 bb d9 54 e2 f1 0f fb 80 9c de

Certificate 3
=== == == == == == == == == == == NO DATA  == == == == == == == == == == == ==
#04 18 30 16 80 14 ab 80 59 c3 65 83 6d 1d 7d 13 bd 19 c3 ec 1a 8f 0d 47 6a a3
```

I was expecting c3's AuthorityKeyIdentifier to be equivalent to c2's SubjectKeyIdentifier. that does not seem to be the case here.

EDIT: some parts of the result seem to match, I have some idea on the "SubjectKeyIdentifier" - it always starts with '#04' followed by the length of the contents (in hex). I now have a certain idea on how to decode the "SubjectKeyIdentifier", but the "AuthorityKeyIdentifier" is still a big mystery to me.

relevant [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523081/why-doesnt-my-key-identifier-match)

Did i do anything wrong with the decoding?
Why are the AuthorityKeyIdentifier not matching correctly against the SubjectKeyIdentifier of the certificate that signed it?

Comment: Could you post the certificates themselves for us to analyse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at the ASN.1 definition of SKI and AKI in RFC5280 (following the links in your question) the difference becomes obvious:

```
SubjectKeyIdentifier ::= KeyIdentifier

AuthorityKeyIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
  keyIdentifier             [0] KeyIdentifier           OPTIONAL,
  authorityCertIssuer       [1] GeneralNames            OPTIONAL,
  authorityCertSerialNumber [2] CertificateSerialNumber OPTIONAL  }

KeyIdentifier ::= OCTET STRING
```

So, the AKI is not an OCTET STRING, but a SEQUENCE of three optional elements. One of these elements is the octet string that can be compared to an SKI.

The [Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguished_Encoding_Rules) determine the byte representation of these ASN.1 structures. The individual bytes of an AKI extension have the following meaning (see [A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html)):

```
04 18 30 16 80 14 82 b7 38 4a 93 aa 9b 10 ef 80 bb d9 54 e2 f1 0f fb 80 9c de

04 OCTET STRING
18 LENGTH
30 SEQUENCE
16 LENGTH
80 CONTEXT-SPECIFIC PRIMITIVE TAG 0
14 LENGTH
.. DATA
```

The first two bytes (04 18) are part of the Extension structure (as explained in the related question [Why doesn't my key identifier match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523081/why-doesnt-my-key-identifier-match)), the actual AKI extension content starts at "30 16".

Your Java code for decoding the AKI should look like this (using Bouncy Castle):

```
byte[] extensionValue = cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.35");
byte[] octets = DEROctetString.getInstance(extensionValue).getOctets();
AuthorityKeyIdentifier authorityKeyIdentifier = AuthorityKeyIdentifier.getInstance(octets);
byte[] keyIdentifier = authorityKeyIdentifier.getKeyIdentifier();
String keyIdentifierHex = new String(Hex.encode(keyIdentifier));
```

And for decoding SKI:

```
extensionValue = cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.14");
octets = DEROctetString.getInstance(extensionValue).getOctets();
SubjectKeyIdentifier subjectKeyIdentifier = SubjectKeyIdentifier.getInstance(octets);
keyIdentifier = subjectKeyIdentifier.getKeyIdentifier();
keyIdentifierHex = new String(Hex.encode(keyIdentifier));
```

Also, both extensions are optional. If your code should work with arbitrary certificates, then a fallback mechanism is necessary (like verifying the signatures).

Comment: thank you for the very detailed answer. a teammate figured this out yesterday, this is exactly the explanation that i got. accepted as the answer. i am still new with using java's crypto/security modules and its starting to make sense now.

Comment: Not just as a fallback, you should always check child.Issuer equals parent.Subject; that works back to v1 with no extensions at all. AKI/SKI *if present* should be an additional check, and may help where one CA has more than one cert (although that's often multiple certs for one key, not certs for multiple keys).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a really quick check, just open the certificate in windows and look for a tab called "Certification Path". It also lets you easily traverse up through the certificate chain if applicable. (I'd post a picture, but apparently don't yet have enough reputation.)